# Build a SELECT statement based on values returned in sys.columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

So, I am trying to figure out how (if possible) to return result set of only 2 columns who's rows are directly proportional to the number of columns in a given table name, without using the dynamic SQL function: **exec**.

Ex.  I have table 'tblA':

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblA](
[ColumnA] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
[ColumnB] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
[ColumnC] [varchar](20) NOT NULL
)
```

And I hav tblB

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblB](
[Column1] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
[Column2] [varchar](20) NOT NULL
)
```

I can locate columns by running:

```
 SELECT c.name From sys.columns c inner join sys.tables t on c.object_id = t.object_id Where t.name = 'tablename'
```

I ultimately want to return a table of 2 columns whose # of rows is equal to the number of columns from the table name I querying.  For example,

```
SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC FROM tblA WHERE ColumnA = ???
```

would ultimately be inserted into a table:

```
TABLE [dbo].[ResultTable](
[ColumnName] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
[ColumnValue] [varchar](max) NOT NULL
)
```

So what the sp returns looks kinda like:

```
----------------------------
| ColumnName | ColumnValue |
----------------------------
| ColumnA    | Hello       |
----------------------------
| ColumnB    | World       |
----------------------------
| ColumnC    | Fubar       |
----------------------------
```

but using tblB would give you

```
----------------------------
| ColumnName | ColumnValue |
----------------------------
| Column1    | ABCDE       |
----------------------------
| Column2    | 12345       |
----------------------------
```

If tblA has X column, then the returned set would have X row, but still two columns.  I know this can be accomplished by using **exec** function, but didn't know if it was possible without using it?

Comment: What is the purpose of this? If you want to use the values from `sys.columns` then you will have to use dynamic SQL to select by the column names.

Comment: @JohnOdom, the purpose is to create a stored proc that given a table name (ex. 'tblA', 'tblB', .... , 'tblN' ), I can do a 'SELECT n1, n2, .... nX FROM tblN.  My issue is that I would like to attempt to create a generic enough sp that would return all columns of a table found in sys.tables regardless of table name.  If I include the function 'exec' in the sp, then doesn't that slow down the sp?

Comment: @Jason Then, again, why aren't you using `SELECT *`?, why would you need a stored procedure at all?

Comment: @Jason I understand where you are going with your stored procedure. As long as you keep your `exec` simple then it shouldn't terribly impact your stored procedure's performance. So what you will need to do is create a variable(s) that will store the column names then use them in your dynamic SQL. It is not possible without exec from what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Lamak He wants to create a generic stored procedure that would let him select all columns regardless of the table name. Sounds unecessary imo.

Comment: @JohnOdom Yeah, I get it. So, he wants a stored procedure that does: `EXEC getAllColumnsFromTable 'TableA'` instead of `SELECT * FROM TableA`. What's the point in doing that?, I don't get it

Comment: I want to really return a 2 column table of a pivoted row from whatever table name I pass in (those columns being 'column name' and 'value in column').  so this statement of select col1, col2, etc... colX from tblA (or 'tblB') WHERE colX = ???? .  This would get put into a temp table of just 'column name' and another of 'value in column' to be returned to the user.  So regardless of tblA or tblB being quiered, I would always get a result set of 2 columns, but the rows returned would equal the # of columns for the given table name.   Whew.... I really hope that makes sense.

Comment: @Jason You should edit your question to include that information so the comments wouldn't be crowded up :).

Comment: @Jason That requirement is very very different as the one explained in the question

Comment: Just when I began to think I understood these requirements.....

Comment: You do realise that you are essentially trying to use SQL for a job that should be done in your presentation layer, don't you?

Comment: what to do if `SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC FROM tblA WHERE ColumnA = ???` returns more than one row? in your output which values will you keep?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ColumnName,  ColumnValue
FROM 
   (SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC FROM tblA) p
UNPIVOT
   (ColumnValue FOR ColumnName IN 
      ([ColumnA], [ColumnB], [ColumnC])
)AS unpvt;
```

Comment: I totally forgot about the `UNPIVOT` +1.